# Output all the taxanomy category names onto page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the below get method that I would like to use as a template to output my category names into an output method:

```
public static function get()
{
    $recipe_categories = get_terms('recipe_categories');
    var_dump($recipe_categories);

    foreach ($recipe_categories as $member_group_term) {

        $member_group_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'recipe',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'recipe_categories',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array($member_group_term->slug),
                    'operator' => 'IN'
                )
            )
        ));

        var_dump($member_group_query);
    }
}
```

Here is the output method that I have:

```
public function output()
{
    // @todo: Grab get() and output
}
```

I can't get it to print out all the 'name' attributes:

Here is what i'm getting:
[image]

Comment: What is the actual problem? Just loop over the array, and then access to property of the current item …

Comment: @misorude, would I loop inside the output method and then return it there? I'm still learning.

Comment: Your `get` should actually return the assembled array, currently you are just var-dumping it. And yes, then you can simply loop over that inside your output method. Declare a variable containing an empty string before the loop, and then append the name of the current item inside the loop (plus whatever additional HTML you might need, to get the desired resulting structure.) And then have the output method return that assembled string.